# Facebook Graph API - How to avoid request limits when accessing a user's photos?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, request, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to fetch user photos and albums using the Facebook Graph API.

As far as I understand (while reading the docs) this is a two step procedure, 1. fetching the id for each photo from the `photos` edge, 2. using the returned array of ids, fetching individual photo nodes.

Fetching individual photo nodes could mean hundreds of requests/s, while having a lot of photos on my profile I have hit the app request limits after a few minutes of testing.

Is there maybe a way to fetch all photos at once (or in fewer requests), in order to avoid request limits?

example implementation:

```
  ...

  var photos = [];

  function fetchPhotos(){
    fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me/photos?type=uploaded&access_token=' + accesstoken, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(photos => photos.json())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    .then(photos => {

      this.fetchPhoto(photos);

    });
  }

  function fetchPhoto(photos){
    for(var i=0; i < photos.data.length; i++){
      fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/' + photos.data[i].id + '?fields=link,width,height&access_token=' + accesstoken, {
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then(photo => photo.json())
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
      .then(photo => {

        photos.push(photo);

      });
    }
  }

  ...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can already get a list with all the fields with one call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me/photos?fields=link,width,height&access_token=...
```

Side Note: If that is client code, why not use the official JS SDK? That way, you don´t need to deal with the Access Token, it gets added automatically.

Comment: It works, however I haven't seen in the docs that [photos edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/) would support these fields directly but I guess while the returned data is of type `photo nodes` the fields can be still applied, right?